# How to list records from the given custom group via API?

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, api, multi-record

I've custom data stored in custom fields. I've submitted few records as part of the same Contact.

I can use the following API to fetch information about custom group by:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('CustomGroup', 'get', ['id' => 77]);
```

which returns:

```
{

    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "id": 77,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "77",
...
            "table_name": "civicrm_value_myform_77",
...
        }
    ]
}
```

In that SQL table, I can see multiple records which belong to Contact (`entity_id=2`).

How I can list those records using API3? In the format that I can count how many records there are.

I can't list based on Contact, because these records belong to the same one.

Basically I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM civicrm_value_myform_77 WHERE entity_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using API4 for this. If you want to get the custom data with API3 you should be able to do this by returning the "custom_" + id of the custom field like so:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => ["custom_4"],
]);
```

And perhaps you can achieve what you want with something like:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getcount', [
  'custom_4' => ['IS NOT NULL' => 1],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also share the approach for API4, is it more flexible?

Comment: Yes, but you can try with the API4 explorer in your install? And check this documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/usage/